# how can I read timestamp with no system interruption?

Tags: c++, linux, linux-kernel

I am using standard library (std::chrono ) to get current time to set time in several messages in a real time application, but this method seems to slow down message processing .

Is there a way to avoid system  interruption or to enhance timestamp reading  during  program execution ?

Comment: Probably you have some specific problem, but in the current form your question is a bit **unclear**. When talk about "enhance" we usually compare it with something we already have; what a method of extracting time you already use? Note, that the term "timestamp" usually refers to a time **mark** of some object (e.g. file). To current time it is better to refer as "current time".

Comment: I am using standard library (std::chrono ) to get current time  to set time in  several messages in a real time application, but this method seems to slow down message processing .

Comment: Writing log messages is sometimes surprisingly complex and time consuming. I am not surprised that it messes up your RT application...

Comment: @AnisBelaid: Your comment has more sence than your current question post. Please, incorporate information from your last comment into the question post.

Comment: @anisBelaid, how much latency are you observing? In Linux, [vDSO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VDSO) bypasses sys call and reduces the cost of getting current time to dozens of nano-seconds (exact number varies depending on hardware).

Comment: The latency jump from hundreds of nanosecond to microseconds per message.

Comment: @AnisBelaid what change made the latency to "jump"? Compiler upgrade? Linux version upgrade or something else? Also I think you'll need to narrow down the problem by doing some performance analysis -- i.e. get the latency breakdown of message processing time to individual function calls. For example, if you have nailed the performance difference is down to chrono::system_clock::now() between two gcc versions, then we'll be able to help. Otherwise, no one knows how your message processing works.

Comment: Sorry I was not accurate , it  is the same compiler but the latency jumped before and after using gettime syscall . In fact I am stamping every packet I am decoding .

Comment: you can always take the rdtsc cpu timer, and use that for pure interval timing.  That's good approach for diagnostic debugging, when dealing with low latency code -- I wrote a C library around it, for diagnostic logging, here --> https://github.com/darrenjs/log2mem     ... but key thing is to realise that even to creation of log strings can be expensive (so these should be done on a separate logging thread).

Comment: @AnisBelaid that makes more sense. When you do a 'ldd <your app>', does it show linux-vdso? If so, can you please write a test program to compare the avg cost of chrono and the raw clock_gettime? I suspect the raw clock_gettime will significantly out perform chrono::xx_clock::now()

Comment: @DarrenSmith, Intel Processor Tracing (or ETM/coresight for arm) is much better for that :-)